# function to hide the navigation bar in swift not working

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to create a function to hide the navigation bar. this the code i have so far but i can not get it to work please help.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 helper.navbar()
}


//function file
func navbar() -> UINavigationController{

    let navigationController = UINavigationController()
   navigationController.navigationBarHidden = false

return navigationController

}
```

Comment: I really didn't get it. You're trying to create a new instance or change to current one? If so (the existent one) your going to have to change its instance instead. If you're creating using the Interface builder there is an IBOutlet for that. Change this value.